# How to get the message of RaiseError of a procedure in another procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, raiseerror

I have two procedures `PROC_A` and `PROC_B`.

In both procedure transaction are managed.

`PROC_B` throws an error by calling `RAISEERROR` and passes a message in certain condition

```
RAISERROR ('Initiator is Inactive', 16, 1, 'Approve Transaction');
```

I am executing (calling) `PROC_B` in `PROC_A`. Now I want to get the error message thrown by `PROC_B` in `PROC_A`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestA
AS
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Initiator is Inactive', 16, 1, 'Approve Transaction'); 
END;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestB
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
    EXEC dbo.TestA;
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE();
    END CATCH
END;
GO

EXEC dbo.TestB;
GO

DROP PROCEDURE dbo.TestB;
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.TestA;
```

Comment: Yes I have done it in similar way ..thanks for the reply

Comment: Frankly speaking I don't know how to mark as answered .. I will do that once I can figure it out.. Sorry for delay response went for lunch.. Sorry once again for not marking as answered